# Converting Varchar2 to Time in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I have a data loaded into a table and i have two columns Time In and Time Out and they are both of type Varchar2. The data loaded into these columns are dates with time  and I want to exclude the dates and populate the column with the time alone. My problem comes with i try to format all the dates in the column to on format, it gives me the error "not a valid month" or "invalid number". I have a query i use to try to select the data in the format. If i could get the query right then I can fix my data.

The query includes

```
SELECT
    to_date(to_char(time_in, 'HH:MI:SS AM'), 'HH:MI:SS AM') time_in,
    to_date(to_char(time_out, 'HH:MI:SS AM'), 'HH:MI:SS AM') time_out
FROM
    loadingtable
```

To recap i have a table with two colums of type varchar2 and the they have data in two formats of date and time.

[image]

and i want to format it to get the time alone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have exactly these two formats or are there other possible?

Comment: I am loading the records from a csv and its alot and so far these are the only two formats and will continue to be the only two formats

Comment: Converting a `DATE` into a string and then back again into a `DATE` seems to be silly. Also using `TO_CHAR()` on a character value is pointless. What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to this:

```
WITH 
function convert_date(str_i VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE
AS
  l_date DATE;
  TYPE format_mask_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(128);
   l_format_masks format_mask_t := format_mask_t(
     'DD/MM/YY HH:MI AM'
    ,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI AM' -- add more if needed
   );
BEGIN
  FOR i IN l_format_masks.FIRST .. l_format_masks.LAST LOOP
    BEGIN
      l_date := TO_DATE(str_i, l_format_masks(i));
      RETURN l_date;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
    END;  
  END LOOP;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
source_tab (time_in, time_out) AS
(
  SELECT '12/2/21 7:03 AM', '12/2/21 4:24 PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12-02-2021 7:01 AM', '15-02-2021 4:00 PM' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(convert_date(time_in),'HH:MI AM') as time_in,
       TO_CHAR(convert_date(time_out),'HH:MI AM') as time_out
 FROM source_tab
```

This is using an inline function - you could create a function instead of using this inline function. It returns NULL if it encounters a format that is doesn't match any of the 2 formats that are listed. You can easily add other formats if needed. The "source_tab" CTE is just to produce some test data, remove that from the query for your own data.

Comment: Kind tip: use this code to **UPDATE** your data (i.e. convert to `DATE` data type) - not only for select.

Comment: Too much brute force in that function. What if there are exceptions caused by something other than a format model mismatch? They will get swallowed by `when others then`.

Comment: @mathguy good point, I have never used an approach like yours - will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression directly in the format model. If you know for sure you have only those two exact models, you can distinguish between two formats: either the string contains a forward-slash, or it does not - and use the corresponding format model in each case. This can be generalized further, to many more "mixed" format models - as long as there are no ambiguities.

Like this:

```
with
  source_tab (time_in, time_out) as (
    select '12/2/21 7:03 AM'   , '12/2/21 4:24 PM'    from dual union all
    select '12-02-2021 7:01 AM', '15-02-2021 4:00 PM' from dual 
  )
select to_date(time_in , case when time_in like '%/%' then 'dd/mm/rr hh:mi AM'
                              else 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi AM' end) as time_in,
       to_date(time_out, case when time_in like '%/%' then 'dd/mm/rr hh:mi AM'
                              else 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi AM' end) as time_out
from   source_tab
;

TIME_IN             TIME_OUT           
------------------- -------------------
2021-02-12 07:03:00 2021-02-12 16:24:00
2021-02-12 07:01:00 2021-02-15 16:00:00
```

(Of course, the **output** shown above depends on my session settings for showing date-times.)

If you have many tables like that, or if you must write many similar queries against this data, you can write a PL/SQL function to convert "string" to "date" (where "string" may use various format models), but it should follow the same general idea. The suggestion of trying different models until one does not throw an exception, as in the "correct answer", doesn't seem like a good practice.

Comment: Hi, i agree with you and both methods work. Thank you for the alternative. I would like to ask you another questions. Can you check a time in oracle sql to see if its in the AM or PM?

Comment: @BasudevSingh - what do you mean by "time in Oracle"? Oracle does not support a `time` data type, it only has `date` which always has both a "date" and a "time" component. (Oracle has an **undocumented** `time` data type, which is best if you don't know about.) Do you mean, if you have a `date` value, how to see if its time component is AM or PM? That is trivial, use `to_char()` with the format model `'AM'` (just like that!) Give it a try and see if that's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

With the two date formats you have, you do not need to use a `CASE` statement or multiple formats and can just use the [string-to-date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5) where:

- You can use any non-alphanumeric character in the date string to match the punctuation symbol in the format string.
- `'RR'` also matches `'RRRR'`.

Which gives you:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( time_in, 'DD-MM-RR HH12:MI AM' ), 'HH24:MI' ) AS time_in,
       TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( time_out, 'DD-MM-RR HH12:MI AM' ), 'HH24:MI' ) AS time_out
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( time_in, time_out ) AS
SELECT '12/2/21 7:03 AM', '12/2/21 4:24 PM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '15-02-2021 7:01 AM', '15-02-2021 04:00 PM' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TIME_IN | TIME_OUT
> :------ | :-------
> 07:03   | 16:24   
> 07:01   | 16:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=924b457f9b878e12889fdad008a43909)*

Answer (score 1):

> I want to exclude the dates and populate the column with the time alone

The question is: What data type to use for this? Let's look at this step by step ...

First of all, it's a bad idea to store datetimes as strings. In your case there are at least two different formats you must account for. Can you guarantee that all strings are valid datetimes in one of the two formats?

The first step should be to convert the strings to real datetimes. Use `COALESCE` and `TO_DATE` with an `ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause to get the datetimes. Strings that don't match either of the two formats result in null:

```
with mytable as (select '12/2/21 7:03 am' as time_in, '15-02-2021 04:00 pm' as time_out from dual)
select 
  coalesce
  (
    to_date(time_in default null on conversion error, 'dd.mm.rr hh:mi am'), 
    to_date(time_in default null on conversion error, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi am')
  ) as start_time,
  coalesce
  (
    to_date(time_out default null on conversion error, 'dd.mm.rr hh:mi am'), 
    to_date(time_out default null on conversion error, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi am')
  ) as end_time
from mytable;
```

Then, Oracle doesn't have a `TIME` data type (just as they don't have a separate `DATE` data type either), they only have a datetime type they call `DATE` inappropriately. So, you cannot really get rid of the date part using this type.

Three options:

1. Store a string instead (by applying `to_char(___, 'hh24:mi')` on the above expressions).
2. Use an `INTERVAL` to store the times (e.g. by applying `cast(___ as timestamp)- trunc(___)` on the above expressions. We need the cast from `DATE` to `TIMESTRING` in order to get an `INTERVAL` and not just a fraction of the day as a number with the subtraction.)
3. Replace the date part with a constant, say, 1990-01-01 (by adding it to the interval we just got, e.g. `date '1990-01-01' + (cast(___ as timestamp)- trunc(___))`).

The following demo shows the second option, which is my preference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=189496f4b97e87e57ed51a20f3696134

Comment: You don't need to cast to a timestamp to get the interval. Just explicitly state that you want the subtraction as an interval (and not as the default number type) using `(date_column - TRUNC( date_column)) DAY TO SECOND` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9c2bef5eb94a6e81b3635e82fe00fd4)

Comment: @MT0: Wow thank you. I didn't know that. I haven't even ever seen this syntax before where `DAY TO SECOND` is used as an operator. Nor am I able to find this in the Oracle docs. Do you know whether this is documented somewhere? I just tried `select 0.5 day to second from dual;` and got a syntax error. I find this weird.

Comment: It is mentioned in [this AskTom question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:742938700346522118) and I'm sure it is mentioned somewhere in the Oracle docs but its difficult to find (I'm having trouble locating it again).

Comment: @MT0: Thank you. This is an interesting link showing that the Oracle developers somehow muddled through to get this working, as they don't cast the expression from number to interval, but cast the expression's operands to force another expression result type. Not the proper way to handle this in my opinion, but well, it works :-)